# When I open blender I have some issues

Tags: mesh, objects

[image: cube]

When I open Blender this is what happens when I start a new project. How do I fix this issue? I also tried to add a Mesh, just as a circle and it did what the second picture shows. I don't even know how this happened.

[image: circle mesh]

Comment: Check if your hardware fulfills the [minimum requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/). If its does, try to update your graphics driver. If it doesn't use an older version of Blender with lower requirements or upgrade your hardware.

Comment: Hi. Please make the title of your question specific to the problem you are having and not just the general topic. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your startup file has some issues. You can go back to the factory startup file by doing the following:

1. Go to *File > Defaults > Load Factory Settings*. This loads in the startup file that would come with a new installation of Blender.
2. Go to *File > Defaults > Save Startup File*. This saves the current .blend file (in this case, the factory one you just loaded) as the startup one.
3. If 1 and 2 do not solve your problem, you may also have to reset your preferences by going to *Edit > Preferences* (while in the factory file), click on the menu button in the bottom left corner, and click *Save Preferences*.
4. If 1, 2, and 3 still do not solve your problem, you may have to reinstall Blender.